# Versioning of hard-to-diff files

Tags: git, svn, mfc

Our department is currently planning to switch from SVN to Git and there are several issues to solve.
One of our products uses `MFC` for its user interface. The issue we would have when switching to Git would be that the UI code is hard to version control without a central locking mechanism like we have in SVN now.
We're using a ribbon bar in our UI. The layout of the ribbon bar is contained in a XML file. The problem is that this XML is a one liner and thus not easily diff-able (if this word even exists).
Another issue is that there are several resource files that contain IDs for the UI elements and thus are tightly coupled with the UI layout files.

With SVN we're using a locking mechanism to lock those files so that our developers don't interfere with each other.
Git doesn't support such mechanisms by its decentralized nature so I'm wondering how one could solve this issue?

The first and simplest idea would be to coordinate changes to these files with the other team members e.g. via chat. The big disadvantage with this approach is that it's easy to forget about this and it's rather tedious for the single developer who wants to get things done.

A second idea would be to agree upon some team members that are exclusively allowed to change those files. Those members would have to communicate among themselves.

Unfortunately I'm not (yet) a git expert so that I can't imagine any more advanced approaches to this problem.
I guess there are similiar problems out there that already got solved using git but I couldn't find anything so far.
I would like to know if this issue can be solved somehow?

Comment: I don’t know exactly how they work, but Git supports what they call “attributes” to customize how some files are diffed. Then you don’t need a locking mechanism.

Comment: The attributes mechanism allows you to specify alternate tools to use for diff and merge operations. Which is fine if you have suitable tools that can be made to work with the expected interface.  In general machine-maintained code (as I assume a one-line XML would be; and if not, just format it in a way diff can handle and be done with it...) can be a problem to accurately diff/merge.  I'm not sure why the multiple files with synchronized ID's would be an issue, though

Comment: Thanks for your answers Daniel and Mark.  

@MarkAdelsberger: The resource files with the IDs are auto generated/updated by Visual Studio and they shouldn't be mixed up. So one has to ensure that all IDs exist in the resource files that are used in the layout files. The IDs are just incrementing numbers so the one who merges has to ensure that all IDs match with the merged layout files. But yeah that's essentially the problem of the developers who merge.

Answer (score 0):

There is no One True General Solution.  Merging is the distributed equivalent of locking, though, for most distributed version control systems.

Quoting (with minor format changes) from my proto-book "concepts and history" chapter, "concurrency model" section (with VCS = version control system, with prefix C and D standing for Centralized and Distributed respectively):

---

Whether centralized or distributed,
any VCS that lets multiple users work independently of each other
must offer some method for dealing with potential conflicts.
As mentioned earlier, one method is *locking:*
before changing a file,
the user must obtain a lock,
which is then released upon committing the change.
This simple method has the obvious problem mentioned earlier
of prohibiting parallel work.
It's possible to make the locks finer-grained—Alice
might lock the top half of the file,
leaving the bottom half available for Bob to lock and change—but
this has scaling issues.
In addition, users and/or administrators
must have ways to break locks
since users will lock files but fail
or forget to unlock them (e.g., after deciding not to commit).

If the VCS provides a *merge* model,
two or more people may work on the same files,
and at defined rendezvous points—in a CVCS,
at check-in / commit time, for instance—they
are given a chance to reconcile their changes.
Merges are also needed when combining branches,
and in modern DVCSes,
the same methods are generally used for both of these.

Note that in a DVCS,
the rendezvous point (and hence any merging)
can occur *after* checkin.
Bob may be able to pick up Alice's work
before doing his own checking-in,
but because the system is distributed,
Bob does not have to wait for Alice
(nor vice versa).

\exercise{Consider
this deferred merge.  What advantages might it provide?
What disadvantages can you think of?}

\answer{One advantage
is that the check-in process is complete.
Since the merge is a separate step,
if anything goes wrong and the merge is deferred,
this does not hold up the actual check-in.
This might not seem all that important,
but in practice it makes a big difference.
CVCSes could potentially allow this too,
but not all of them do.
(CVS is particularly notorious here.)
One potential disadvantage
is that by the time the merge occurs,
the programmers involved—who are often
the best candidates for doing the merge—may
have moved to other projects,
or forgotten some details of why they made certain changes.}

---

The above does not get into *merge drivers*, but Git's have a small flaw.  You can write or select a merge driver that handles, or at least leaves-conflicted and therefore forces users to handle, complex and poorly-machine-managed merges (such as XML files).  This works pretty well in practice, except for one case: when merging commits *X* and *Y* with common base *B*, if only one of *X* or *Y* has modified some file with respect to *B*, the custom merge driver is never even consulted.  In some cases this produces the right answer, and in some it does not.

Comment: This is not in response to the question at hand but in response to the last sentences of your answer. If you merge two branches where only one of them has changed a particular file, in what cases would it be incorrect for the merge to take the changed file? I assume git will take the whole file if the other branch has an exact copy of the common base version. We are rather new to git at our place so I'm latching onto potential problems in the hope of avoiding them so any insight you can provide would be most welcome.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: People sometimes put a file in a branch that's meant to be branch-specific, but does not play well with Git's branch model (where names are lightweight pointers). Usually it's just a mistake to try this in the first place, but see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42997079/1256452) and all the comments after my answer...