# Is it possible to set specific files in git to always merge as --our?

Tags: git, github, merge, configuration, git-merge-conflict

I have a file that has a list of feature acceptance tests I desire to be executed in Jenkins during pull requests.  This file needs to be checked in so that Jenkins has access to it, but it also means it will be different on every branch, depending upon the feature being worked on.  As a result, this file is flagged in every pull request in github as having merge conflicts.

**QUESTION: Is there a way that I can set this single file (only) to always merge as --our so that I and my team don't have to resolve this conflict in every branch I ever work on?**

I will always want this file to overwrite whatever used to be there, but I cannot seem to find a way to set configurations for a specific file only that can do this.

The .gitconfig isn't checked in, so I'm not sure how to write a custom driver that everyone else would automatically get to use.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Add a custom merge driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49143050/7976758).

Comment: Thanks @phd  Unfortunately since the .gitconfig isn't checked in, it doesn't propagate to everyone, so this would work for me personally, but not easily for the rest of the team without them making the same additions to their .gitconfig files :(
(I updated the original question to note this too)

Comment: Besides the fact that `.gitconfig` does not propagate (though `.gitattributes` does!), there is also the annoying fact that a custom merge driver simply does not achieve the desired result. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/42997079/1256452 for more.

Comment: Thanks @torek - I guess I need to rethink how this works.